# Disable webpage cache programmatically

Tags: android, caching, browser

I have an app that loads an URL. My problem is that it shows me the old version of that webpage and never loads the new one(I think it keeps the webpage in cache and loads it from there even though I have wireless connection). Is there a way to programmatically specify my app to never keep the webpages in memory? Or maybe I have a different problem that need another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this(**not tested**) for deleting the cache at the end of session:

```
private int clearCacheFolder(){
deletedFiles = 0;
File dir = context.getCacheDir();
if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            for (File child:dir.listFiles()) {

                    //delete subderictories
                    if (child.delete()) {
                        deletedFiles++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
return deletedFiles;
}
```

or

```
setAppCacheEnabled(false);
```

for disabling it

Answer (score 1):

//cache is per-application, so this will clear the cache for all WebViews used.
clearCache(boolean includeDiskFiles)
// prob not what you want
clearFormData()
// prob not what you want
clearHistory()